# which is the best encryption method to use in android?

Tags: android, encryption

I have found so many encryption method available in java. i have read that the AES is the best.

actually my need is file encryption in android. can i use AES method? or any another simple way?

Thanks In advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use AES and it is a very good option. Whether or not it's the best is about impossible to say. For security purposes there's no concern if you use it right (the bigger concern would be things like key management and follow best practices). In terms of performance it might be an issue on some Android devices. You might want to use Blowfish instead for performance. It's no less secure at this time. Here's an [example](http://pastie.org/pastes/1781894) of encrypting and decrypting a file to help you get started with the code.

Comment: Blowfish is incredibly slow on Android. It can take minutes to encrypt a 3 mb file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to use it for, you may want an encryption algorithm which is much slower than the 'best' so Blowfish is generally recommended as it can be set to varying speed levels.

(The reason for wanting slow code on mobile devices is to make it unfeasible to brute force if an attacker gains physical control over the device)